# Show $(1+x_1)(1+x_2)...(1+x_n)\geq2^n$ given $x_1x_2...x_n=1$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, holder-inequality

> Show $(1+x_1)(1+x_2)...(1+x_n)\geq2^n$ given $x_1x_2...x_n=1$ and that all $x_i $ are positive reals.

I think simple AM-GM-HM must work, but I am missing on something trivial.

Comment: Please include the question in the body of the post, not only in its title. // Got anything from an answer below?

Comment: See also [Inequality in Algebra: $1 \leq x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n$ implies that $2^{n} \leq (1 + x_1)(1+x_2) \cdots (1 + x_n).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1266094) and [Let $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^+$ and $a_1\cdot a_2\cdots a_n=1$, prove that $(1+a_1) \cdot (1+a_2) \cdot \dots \cdot (1+a_n) \geq 2^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1911849). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24(1%2Bx_1)(1%2Bx_2)...(1%2Bx_n)%5Cgeq2%5En%24&p=1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By AM-GM inequality,

$$(1+x_i) \geq 2 \sqrt x_i$$

Taking product from $i=1$ to $n$, we get the desired result.

Comment: I like how this avoids using the more general AM-GM that some students aren't familiar with and keeps it as elementary as can be.

Answer (score 2):

$$LHS \geqslant 2\sqrt{x_1}\cdot 2\sqrt{x_2}\cdots 2\sqrt{x_n}=2^n.$$

Comment: Note: $1+x^2 \ge 2x$ since $(x-1)^2 \ge 0$.

Comment: Yes, substitute $x$ by $\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Follows directly after some manipulation of $AM-GM$ on $x_i,1$

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I wrote above.

Answer (score 2):

Not substantially different form other answers, but perhaps an interesting manipulation: multiply the LHS by $$1=1^{-1/2}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}x_k^{-1/2}$$ obtaining $$\prod_{j=1}^k(1+x_j)=\prod_{j=1}\left(\frac1{x_j^{1/2}}+x_j^{1/2}\right)$$

And then use the fact that (for the reason you prefer) $$\min\left\{ \frac1x+x\,:\,x>0\right\}=2$$

Answer (score 1):

The brute force approach is:

$$(1+x_1)(1+x_2)\cdots(1+x_n)=\sum_{S\subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}}\prod_{i\in S}x_i$$

But by AM/GM, since there are $2^n$ subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$, you get:

$$\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{S\subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}}\prod_{i\in S}x_i \geq \sqrt[2^n]{x_1^{2^{n-1}}\cdots x_n^{2^{n-1}}}=1$$

This is because:

$$\prod_{S\subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}}\prod_{i\in S} x_i=x_1^{2^{n-1}}\cdots x_n^{2^{n-1}}$$

Answer (score 1):

By Holder
$$(1+x_1)(1+x_2)...(1+x_n)\geq\left(1+\sqrt[n]{x_1x_2...x_n}\right)^n=2^n$$